# Dart Unhandled exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, int>' has no instance getter

Tags: dart

Please help me understand why this sort doesn't work.  I've read [Dart's documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#what-is-soundness) several times and it's just not clicking why this doesn't sort how I expect it to.

```dart
void main() {
  final hand1 = {
    'ranking': 1,
  };

  final hand2 = {
    'ranking': 2,
  };
  final hand3 = {
    'ranking': 1,
  };

  List players = [hand1, hand2, hand3];

  players.sort((a, b) => b.ranking.compareTo(a.ranking));

  // Expected players to become
  // [hand2, hand1, hand3]
}
```

Dart complains:

```bash
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, int>' has no instance getter 'ranking'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:1
Tried calling: ranking
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/primetimetran/Desktop/projects/flutpoke/poker_class.dart:15:28)
#2      Sort._insertionSort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:69:36)
#3      Sort._doSort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:58:7)
#4      Sort.sort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:33:5)
#5      ListMixin.sort (dart:collection/list.dart:356:10)
#6      main (file:///Users/primetimetran/Desktop/projects/flutpoke/poker_class.dart:15:11)
#7      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

I lack an understanding of how the [internals of Dart work](https://dart.dev/guides/language/coming-from/js-to-dart) I know.

Thanks in advance~!

Answer (score 1):

This does not work, because Dart is not JavaScript and you can't access a map element like a field, instead you have to access it this way `b['ranking']!`. The bang operator (`!`) is [because of null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-do-i-signal-that-the-return-value-from-a-map-is-non-nullable).